# Sqlite3 : "Database is locked" error

Tags: cocoa, sqlite

In my cocoa application I am maintaining a SQLite db within resources folder and trying to do some select, delete operations in it but after some time it starts giving me 'Database is locked' error.

The methods which I am using for select delete operations are as follows:

// method to retrieve data

```
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            sqlite3_close(database);
            NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
        }

        NSLog(@"mailBodyFor:%d andFlag:%d andFlag:%@",UId,x,Ffolder);
        NSMutableArray *recordsToReturn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
        NSString *tempMsg;


        const char *sqlStatementNew;
        NSLog(@"before switch");
        switch (x) {
            case 9:
            //  tempMsg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM users_messages"];
                tempMsg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT message,AttachFileOriName as oriFileName,AttachmentFileName as fileName FROM users_messages WHERE id = (select message_id from users_messages_status where id= '%d')",UId];
                NSLog(@"mail body query - %@",tempMsg);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        sqlStatementNew = [tempMsg cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatementNew;

        NSLog(@"before if statement");
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatementNew, -1, &compiledStatementNew, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"the sql is finalized");
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatementNew) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSMutableDictionary *recordDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

                NSString *message;
                if((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatementNew, 0)){
                    message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatementNew, 0)];
                }
                else{
                    message = @"";
                }
                NSLog(@"message - %@",message);

                NSString *oriFileName;
                if((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatementNew, 1)){
                    oriFileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatementNew, 1)];
                }
                else{
                    oriFileName = @"";
                }
                NSLog(@"oriFileName - %@",oriFileName);

                NSString *fileName;
                if((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatementNew, 2)){
                    fileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatementNew, 2)];
                }
                else{
                    fileName = @"";
                }
                NSLog(@"fileName - %@",fileName);

                [recordDict setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
                [recordDict setObject:oriFileName forKey:@"oriFileName"];
                [recordDict setObject:fileName forKey:@"fileName"];

                [recordsToReturn addObject:recordDict];
                [recordDict release];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatementNew);
            sqlite3_close(database);
            NSLog(@"user messages return -%@",recordsToReturn);

            return recordsToReturn;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Error while creating retrieving mailBodyFor in messaging '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            sqlite3_close(database);

        }
```

// method to delete data

```
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }

    NSString *deleteQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"delete from users_messages_status where id IN(%@)",ids];
    NSLog(@"users_messages_status msg deleteQuery - %@",deleteQuery);

    sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmnt;
    const char *sql = [deleteQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmnt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }   
    else{
        NSLog(@"successful deletion from users_messages");
    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmnt)){
        NSLog(@"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Things are going wrong in this sequence

1. Data is retrieved
2. 'Database is locked' error arises on performing delete operation.
3. When I retry to perform 1st step.. it now gives same error.

Can anyone suggest me:

1. If I am doing anything wrong or missing some check?
2. Is there any way to unlock it when it gives locked error?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: Use [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).  It makes dealing with SQLite databases infinitely easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is really uncommon that open/close the database every time you access.

If it is your intended scenario, it would be much better to use a normal file.

Open the database at startup and close at exit. This could solve all your problems.

Comment: hi 9dan... thanx for you reply :) I did what you suggested by - opening db when application is launched and closing it, when application quits, but now it is giving this error message when I tried to retrieve some data - 'library routine called out of sequence'..can you suggest some solution for it?

Comment: @Miraaj well, any chance problem of threading? check SQLite FAQ on thread safety: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6